# how to pattern match event.data in scalajs

Tags: scala.js

I would like to match different events on my `window#postMessage` handler but I can not match native traits. So how could I solve this:

```
@js.native
trait XY extends js.Object {
  val x: AnyVal = js.native
  val y: AnyVal = js.native
}

@js.native
trait DataEvent extends js.Object {
  val c: String = js.native                   // chart
  val s: String = js.native                   // dataSet
  val d: XY = js.native                       // xy data
  val x: Seq[XY] = js.native                  // eXtra data
}

object ChartApi extends JSApp {
  def receiveMessage(event: Any): Unit = {
    event match {
      case DataEvent => ???
      case _ => println("else")
    }

    println(s"lala $event")
  }

  def main(): Unit = {
    // add window event handler
    dom.window.addEventListener("message", (event: MessageEvent) => receiveMessage(event.data), false)
    println("Hello world!")

  }
}
```

I have different charts in different iframes and I need to send events like "add this data" or "clear data" via postMessage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS traits do not have an identity at run-time, which is why you cannot directly test whether an arbitrary object is an instance of a JS trait.

Instead, you need to go the JS way, and test for the presence of a field that uniquely identifies the interface represented by the trait, among other possible choices. For example:

```scala
if (event.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
  // it must be a DataEvent, because the alternatives do not have a 'd' field
  val e = event.asInstanceOf[DataEvent]
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Usually, we don't like to do that, though. So in a messaging protocol with several kinds of messages like this, we typically have an explicit `messageType` field or something like that. If you make sure that all `DataEvent` messages a `messageType = "data"` field, you can do:

```scala
if (event.messageType == "data") {
  val e = event.asInstanceOf[DataEvent]
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

You can encode this "type test" in an extractor:

```scala
object DataEvent {
  def unapply(event: Any): Option[DataEvent] =
    if (event.messageType == "data") Some(event.asInstanceOf[DataEvent])
    else None
}
```

which you can then use in a pattern match like this:

```scala
event match {
  case DataEvent(event) => ???
  case _ => println("else")
}
```

Finally, you may want to consider a serialization/pickling library to take care of all your messages as case classes instead. See https://www.scala-js.org/libraries/libs.html for a list of such libraries.